# ArcGIS - Building a model that selects objects and joins fields

Tags: python, attributes, arcgis

I think I've forgotten to mention that I am using ArcGIS...

I have 2 layers, a neighborhood map and a group of geocoded addresses. Each neighborhood has a unique ID to it, that I need to join the fields from the neighborhood to the properties.

I'm trying to build a model. The steps that I am going through selects each neighborhood one at a time, then creates a new neighborhood layer. Then selects all addresses within that neighborhood, and creates a new layer of those addresses, and then joins the fields by adding the neighborhood info to the properties.

I'm trying to do this but I literally am stumbling through the whole thing. The data that I am working with is time series data on house properties. Neighborhoods stay constant.

My workflow is as described above, and my thought is to use "for" and choose the values 0-241 from the neighborhood ID - this is what changes through iteration - and use those value in the select layer by attribute. Then with that outputted layer, select the properties contained within that layer, then join the 2 outputs.

But I can't seem to figure out how to use the value in the iteration in the expression in "select by attribute"

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What data are trying to work with? What format is it in? Why are you talking about "scaping the neighborhood id"?

Comment: I updated the question, I'm having trouble selecting the value of the ID and having it change through each iteration